# Asp.Net Core & Sqlite connection string in appsettings.json - cannot open database

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core

I'm testing Hangfire in Asp.net Core 3.1 app. I want to persist data to sqlite database. I added connection string into appsettings.json file

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"Default": "Data Source=C:\\database\\hangfireDb.db; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True;"},
```

Here is Startup class

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();


        services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
                     .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                     .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                     .UseSQLiteStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseHangfireServer();
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Connection to database cannot be established

```
SQLite.SQLiteException: 'Could not open database file: Data Source=C:\database\hangfireDb.db; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True; (CannotOpen)'
```

I can open database if I use only a path to database

```
services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
                     .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                     .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                     .UseSQLiteStorage("C:\\database\\hangfireDb.db"));
```

Or

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"Default": "C:\\database\\hangfireDb.db"},
```

This does not look like a proper connection string. I think I'm missing something. Connection string should include "Data Source" and any additional tag, but in this case only path to database works.

Comment: What does `Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")` return (debug it and check, don't guess)?

Comment: It returns entire string ""Data Source=C:\\database\\hangfireDb.db; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True;"

Comment: Perhaps parse the data source out and pass it in (since the use of the path **is** working for you)?

Comment: At this point I will only use a path. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> This does not look like a proper connection string

Indeed.

You're using [Hangire.Storage.SQLite](https://github.com/raisedapp/Hangfire.Storage.SQLite) (according to the call to `UseSQLiteStorage`), which [uses](https://github.com/raisedapp/Hangfire.Storage.SQLite/blob/0236edea24d5125c03ca8655990dbf46441670fd/src/main/Hangfire.Storage.SQLite/Hangfire.Storage.SQLite.csproj#L30) a minimal SQLite implementation, [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/), and uses the [constructor that only accepts a path string, not a connection string](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs#L250).

So you can't pass parameters to SQLite using the connection string with this library, as far as I can see.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that. Unfortunately, this is the only currently working sqlite extension for hangfire. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hangire.Storage.SQLite only accepts a path to the database, not a connection string.
You should pass C:\database\hangfireDb.db and not Data Source=C:\database\hangfireDb.db ...